# Positioning Elements: Div on top of another div

Tags: html, css, position

Live page: [Link](http://sharehomme.com/ko/posts/index_masonry)

I have a top nav bar that has a `fixed` position, and `oblique` color.
This nav bar should be placed on top of all the posts as you scroll down. However, when you check the live page at the link above, the pictures are placed on top of the top nav bar, not the other way around.

On the other hand, this [view](http://sharehomme.com/) is working as I'd like it to be.

Could someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:1` to `.nav`

```
.nav {
background-color: black;
padding-bottom: 2px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css class like this

```
.fixed_pos {
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you have the following html.

```
<tag1>
</tag1>
<tag2>
</tag2>
```

tag2 will always be layered above tag1 if they were positioned. That is what is happening in your case. So what I'd suggest just like @Sowmya above is use z-index but on a different tag.

```
.fixed_pos{
z-index: 1; /*any z-index would do here*/
}
```